# Why go routines behave like that?

Tags: multithreading, go, goroutine

I am reading a book so called Go in action and I got a bit confused by the goroutines part of the book, basically I want to understand two things about the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var counter int = 0
var wg sync.WaitGroup
var mtx sync.Mutex

func main() {
    wg.Add(2)

    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)

    go incCounter("A")
    go incCounter("B")

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(counter)
}

func incCounter(prefix string) {
    fmt.Println("Started thread ", prefix)
    defer wg.Done()
    mtx.Lock()
    {
        fmt.Println("Incrementing counter from ", prefix)
        counter = counter + 1
        fmt.Println("Passing to another thread")
        runtime.Gosched()
        for i := 1; i < 100; i++ {
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            fmt.Println("Thread still executing ", prefix)
        }
    }
    mtx.Unlock()
}
```

The output is:

```
Started thread  B
Incrementing counter from  B
Passing to another thread
Started thread  A
Thread still executing  B
Thread still executing  B
Thread still executing  B
Thread still executing  B
```

1. Why does it executes first the goroutine B? since in the code the goroutine A comes first, I was expecting it to run first as well.
2. The goroutine B uses the .Gosched method to allow goroutine A to start its execution, but since the mutex is locked, goroutine A will be waiting for the unlock. At this time, I setted GOMAXPROCS to only one logical processor, why tho it appears that the two goroutines are running in parallel? Is this actually supose to happen?

As I tought, setting the gomaxprox to one would allow only one goroutine to be executed at a time, but in this case it seems it's not what is happening, it really appears both goroutines are running in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goroutines run concurrently. That means, if there are processors available, the scheduler may schedule them to run in parallel. If there is only one processor available, they will still run concurrently, but only one goroutine will be running at any given moment.

The Go runtime does not guarantee which goroutine will run first. So the order in which a group of newly created goroutines run will be random,

Comment: Thank you for the response, if the order in which a group of newly created goroutines is random, why tho every time I execute my code I see first he output of goroutibe "B"?

Comment: @PedroSturmer, just because there is no defined ordering does not mean that it will be different every time, just that there is no guarantee it will be the same every single time.